# I get a segmentation fault when trying to read a file

Tags: c, gcc, debian, fopen, fgets

I've looked up on how to use fgets function and hence I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
       FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

       if (file != NULL)
       {
           char line[100];
           while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
           {
               printf("%s", line);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

I compile the program with:

```
gcc main.c
```

And run it with:

```
./a.out textdoc.txt
```

The file textdoc.txt has some jibberish lines (it is not empty):

```
ageagea gea g
geagae g g g g
eagae ge g ga a a fea
gea hr hr a faw
```

What I've noticed is that when I reach the fgets() line of code, I get a segmentation fault.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: I didn't get seg fault too :<

Comment: `voidmain.c:3:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]`

Comment: Your call to `fgets` looks perfectly correct.  I tried compiling and running your program, and it worked fine -- no segmentation fault.  Your actual problem is probably something peculiar to your environment, that we can't even see.  Are you sure you transcribed your code perfectly accurately here?

Comment: The usual reasons for segmentation faults when calling `fgets` are (1) `line` is an uninitialized pointer variable that doesn't point anywhere yet, and (2) the input file couldn't be opened, so the `file` pointer is null.  But you've handled both of those issues properly, so they don't appear to be your problem.

Comment: @SteveSummit, I've just rerun that code again. I've missed ")" as someone noted when I transcribed that code manually. Seems something is off. I've just tried online compiler on which it works fine. Probably something is broken on my OS.

Comment: Before C99 (I think) `void main()`  would return a *random* value to the caller. On x86 this is probably in the AX register, which could contain the return value of the final `printf()` or of the failing `fgets()`.

Comment: @wildplasser what you said is too guru knowledge. :D

Comment: Before trying to become a guru, you could try to comply to the (hidden) prototype for `main()`, which is `int main(void);` or `int main(int, char**);`. You don't have to understand why, (yet) just do it correctly.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  Note: `gcc` would complain about the invalid function signature: `void main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   For `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Comment: always check for (and handle) errors.  So when the number of command line parameters is not 2)  `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName\n", argv[0] )`  So when `fopen` fails: `#include <stdlib.h> ... perror( "fopen failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`